# Syntax Guide for ActionScript 3.0

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Is there a practical "crash" guide for writing ActionScript 3. There's migration books from as2 to as3, but I'm not migrating.

People that have programmed in C seem to understand the math concepts and arguments. Books, links, a better debugging panel would all be helpful.

Here's my ideas, any suggestions.

## SIMPLE EXAMPLES

"." is the "to drill in to folders or classes"

## LIST OF CLASSES

"shows the path to most-used methods"

## ARGUMENT STRUCTURE

"anatomy of argument, snippets"

## LINKS

http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/as3withflashcs3/?page=3
http://flashspeaksactionscript.com/actionscript-20-to-30-migration-cheatsheet/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend **Essential ActionScript 3** from Colin Moock.  Starts at the beginning and Colin explains things really well and in depth.

http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596526948/

Comment: Ya, it's a really solid book. I've got 2 copies! One at home and another in the office.

Comment: Flipping through it now. Thanks.

Comment: Along the same lines, I found this. http://www.javascriptworkshop.com/wp-content/uploads/pdf/LVSOnline_ActionScriptBasics_wk1.pdf

Answer (score 0):

"practical crash guide " and since you state math i assume that is of interest to you

theres just 1 book id recommend thats worth checking out [Foundation Actionscript 3.0 Animation: Making Things Move! By Keith Peters](http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?page_id=915) .It is FUN and a must read for people learning as3.

Comment: It's got chapters on trig and physics. I'll be studying this for a while. Thanks